# How do I implement LevelDB persistence in ActiveMQ in Mule?

Tags: jms, mule, leveldb

Am i able to persist message data (like logging) using levelDB for JMS ActiveMQ in Mule? Is it done by the "Transaction" property?

Found JMS Transaction, XA Transaction, and so.
But i can't understand the usage of the values in there.

e.g: for JMS Transaction, i got the Actions = ALWAYS_BEGIN, BEGIN_OR_JOIN, ALWAYS_JOIN, JOIN_IF_POSSIBLE.

What's the usage of these actions? :S

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking: it seems you ask about configuring log4j to write to LevelDB, configuring ActiveMQ to persist messages in LevelDB and how do JMS transactions work.

Comment: configure ActiveMQ to persist messages in LevelDB and how do JMS trans. work :) so i can learn that too. Thanks always for your reply, David!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some reading for you on ActiveMQ, JMS and Mule transactions:

- https://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jms-concepts004.htm#sthref2212
- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Transaction+Management
- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Single+Resource+Transactions

Comment: Thanks let me check it out :) if something comes up i will ask ^_^

Comment: If it's about ActiveMQ persistence create a new question and use the `activemq` tag.

Comment: Yeah but i need to know about the LevelDB. I will keep searching in google ^_^

Comment: Okey so it looks like the Transaction isn't what i need.